# Visual return value for pd.date_range incorrect (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For one reason or another I wanted to split a data frame using dates generated by pd.date_range

```
test=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01',end='2020-06-30',freq='6h'))
test['A']=range(0,len(test),1)
split_list=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01',end='2020-06-30',freq='m')
display(split_list)
display(test.loc[:'2020-01-31'])
display(test.loc[:split_list[0]])
```

I would have expected the same result for both approaches but as you can see below although the first value is displayed as '2020-01-31' it actually is treated as '2020-01-31 00:00:00' resulting in 3 missing values.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFWTy.jpg)

Is this behavior intended?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, that is the intended behavior. The "visual return" is as a date, since you have selected a frequency higher or equal to a day when constructing the `pd.date_range`, and no special timezone, however the underlying value is a `Timestamp`.

In the first case, when you directly slice by a string representation of the datetime (e.g. `"2020-01-31"`), Pandas uses what it calls ["Partial string indexing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing), which is essentially a convenience inbuilt into Pandas, that allows you to filter by only a specific year, month or date, even if the index is a full-fledged `DatetimeIndex` (which in your case, it is). As you'll see in the linked documentation, if you slice in the following way, you include all the timestamps (rows / index values) of the last date:

```
dft['2013-1':'2013-2-28'] # example from documentation
```

"This specifies a stop time that includes all of the times on the last day." ->> all timestamps within January 2013 and up to the very last timestamp of Feb 28, 2013 will be included in the selection.

On the other hand, in the second case (`display(test.loc[:split_list[0]])`), you are actually specifying a very concrete timestamp for the end of your slice. This timestamp is `'2020-01-31 00:00:00'`, which is the midnight (earliest time) of the 31st of January. This means that the remaining timestamps on that date will be excluded.

Another way to demonstrate is by using the index itself to slice:

```py
## PARTIAL STRING INDEXING
test.loc[:'2020-01-01'] 

#output
           A
2020-01-01 00:00:00 0
2020-01-01 06:00:00 1
2020-01-01 12:00:00 2
2020-01-01 18:00:00 3

## STRICT DATETIME INDEXING
test.loc[:test.index[0]]

# output

            A
2020-01-01  0
```

What happens here is that in `test.loc[:'2020-01-01']`, `'2020-01-01'` is interpreted as a string representation of a *date*, not a datetime. Due to the Pandas convention mentioned above, it will filter the index for *all* datetimes **up to and including** the **date** '2020-01-01'. Therefore you don't lose any of the timestamps in that date.

On the other hand, `test.loc[:test.index[0]]` compares to `test.index[0]`, which is exactly equal to the timestamp `Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00', freq='6H')`. This means that slicing will say "find me all the datetimes in the index **up to and including** the **timestamp** '2020-01-01 00:00:00'. Which means that only this one timestamp will be selected for the 1st of January. Every other timestamp on that date happens after midnight (notice that midnight is the earliest time of the day, not the latest).

Finally, about representation: as mentioned in the comment, `split_list` is actually in your case a `DatetimeIndex`, so, although when you print it you only see string representations of *dates*, it consists of *datetimes*. You can see this by printing the first one, for example:

```
split_list
#output
Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M')
```

Since this is a date range with frequency higher to or equal than a day, it will print as a date, not a timestamp.

Comment: First, thanks for your support!
Second, I showed that slicing by index leads to a different result. Problem is, why does date_range show the less specific variant without hh:mm:ss when it actually uses  hh:mm:ss and why does it cut (more or less) the last day of the month when using freq='m', resulting in "from: month-1day, to: month-1day"? And is there an integrated option to circumvent this behavior(I didn't find one.)?

Comment: @FloKi Your second question is answered above: essentially Pandas "cuts" the last day because the date is not actually `2020-01-31` but it's the timestamp `2020-01-31 00:00:00`, which means the midnight between 30-31 of January (you can check this by printing `split_list[0]`, which returns `Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M')`). Therefore the subsequent timestamps in your series are not included. The first question is because you have selected a frequency of a day or higher, which means that when you just print the date range, it's displayed as `2020-01-31` instead of the full timestamp

Comment: @FloKi I added some more detail per your question above.

Comment: Really appreciate the time you put into this. Also figured out that for slicing by months using an approach with freq='MS' is most likely the way to go as this returns YYYY-MM-01 00:00:00 avoiding potentially cutting of a day (Also true for 'QS' and 'YS').